# Facebook group saving

Tags: facebook, archiving

**Question:**

Wondering how I can save a private and public Facebook group just for myself as an offline HTML document forever that I can access freely without logging on to Facebook group?

I essentially want to archive the group so that I can access the data offline anytime without needing to open a browser that requires login. Details of what I want to save include offline access to all hosted files and videos.

**What I’ve tried:**

I’ve saved a private Facebook group as an HTML document through Safari and Google Chrome. If I open this saved HTML document it opens a browser with the link of the web page. The problem is that I first need to login to see this Facebook group. I can’t see the contents, because it can’t save all the data from the web page.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As our site is about recommending **software** (not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185)): What OS should the software run on? What is the price limit?

Comment: This is better suited at  e.g. Super User, maybe Web Applications.